# Creating a new directory returns mkdir(): File exists

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to make a new directory to store images in I'm getting

> Error: mkdir(): File exists.

I'm not sure what this could be... My code

```
Storage::makeDirectory(public_path('img/uploads/projects' . $project->id), 0777);
```

My goal is to create a new folder for every project and put their images in it.

Comment: have you checked if.. well.. the directory `'img/uploads/projects'.$project->id` *already exists?*

Comment: without seeing `Storage::makeDirectory` it is very hard to answer

Comment: @RamRaider It is in the main post ?

Comment: Are you sure `$project->id` is defined? Perhaps try `echo ('img/uploads/projects' . $project->id);` first.

Answer (score 2):

Check first file exists. If not create folder.

```
$path='img/uploads/projects' . $project->id;
if (!file_exists($path)) {
    mkdir($path, 0777, true);
}
```

Comment: is it going to inside of if condition?